How to Prevent Concurrent Enrollment and Handle Slot Availability in Firestore Database with React
I'm developing a web application where users can enroll in elective subjects, and each elective subject has a limited number of slots available. I'm encountering an issue where multiple users can enroll simultaneously, even when there's only one slot available.
const handleApprove = async () => {
  if (isEnrolled || isConfirming) {
    return; 
  }

  setIsConfirming(true);

  const shouldEnroll = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to enroll?");

  setIsConfirming(false);

  if (shouldEnroll) {
    try {
      const firestore = firebase.firestore();
      const electiveRef = firestore.collection("electives").doc(project.id);
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

      await firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const electiveDoc = await transaction.get(electiveRef);
        if (!electiveDoc.exists) {
          throw new Error("Elective document does not exist!");
        }

        const electiveData = electiveDoc.data();
        const updatedSlots = electiveData.slots - 1;

        if (updatedSlots >= 0) {
         
          const updatedElectiveDoc = await transaction.get(electiveRef);
          const updatedElectiveData = updatedElectiveDoc.data();
          const remainingSlots = updatedElectiveData.slots;

          if (remainingSlots >= 0) {
            
            transaction.update(electiveRef, { slots: updatedSlots });

  
            await userRef.update({
              isEnroll: true,
              elective: project.name,
              subjectCode: project.details,
            });
            
            logout();
            setIsEnrolled(true);
          } else {
            alert("No available slots for enrollment in this elective.");
            setIsEnrolled(false); // Reset isEnrolled if enrollment fails
          }
        } else {
          alert("No available slots for enrollment.");
          setIsEnrolled(false); // Reset isEnrolled if there are no available slots
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error enrolling:", error);
      alert("An error occurred while enrolling. Please try again.");
      setIsEnrolled(false); // Reset isEnrolled if enrollment fails
    }
  }
};

Multiple users can still enroll when there's only one slot available, and users can enroll even when there are no slots left.
I need to ensure that:

Only one user can enroll when there's only one slot available even if they enroll at the exact same time.
Users are prevented from enrolling when there are no available slots left.

I expected that by using Firestore transactions, only one user would be able to enroll when there's only one slot available, and users would be prevented from enrolling when there are no available slots left. I checked online solutions and every post just told me to implement transactions .

I would recommend to do less things in the transaction. Limiting it to only handle the enrollment logic.
You can pass out a return value from the transaction  to allow you to know its status and do all the failed/succeded to enroll logic outside after result.
Also, do the user document update with the transaction so that the updated fields are rolling back if the transaction fails/retries.
Try something like this
const didEnroll = await firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const electiveDoc = await transaction.get(electiveRef);
        if (!electiveDoc.exists) {
          throw new Error("Elective document does not exist!");
        }

        const electiveData = electiveDoc.data();
        if (electiveData.slots == 0) {
          // Do all the other failed to enroll actions after returning this
          return false;
        }
        
        // Only do things if there are available slots. 
        // Let the transaction just end with no change if nothing to be done
        transaction.update(electiveRef, {            
          slots: firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1), // Decrement the counter directly
        });

        // Update with transaction so its values are rolling back on retry
        await transaction.update(userRef, {
          isEnroll: true,
          elective: project.name,
          subjectCode: project.details,
        });

        return true; 
      });


Thanks it really saved lots of time for me . Your explanation was precise and clear .

Happy to hear that the input was valuable.
